# including "vartype" library to the beginning of the C program

Tags: c, include, libraries

I want to have some information about (#include)
in the beginning of my C program.
What does this library do?I have search before and found nothing.....

Comment: What library? Be more specific and detailed in your question.

Comment: You need to spend more than a week reading a good book about C programming.

Comment: I Dont know why my question in edit mode is complete but in the view mode is incomplete. I just want to know what is the usage of (#include <vartype> ) library. I understand what is include, but i coudnt find vartype anywhere......

Answer (score 1):

`#include` is a preprocessor directive, not a library. You can read below Wikipedia page about it.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_directive

Comment: I Dont know why my question in edit mode is complete but in the view mode is incomplete. I just want to know what is the usage of (#include <vartype> ) library. I understand what is include, but i coudnt find vartype anywhere......